# Map or String: what do I have to use?

Tags: soql, map, string, product

I need to create a method that receives three strings: color, brand and model.
Would it be better to put a map that would receive for example ("color", "blue") or directly receive "blue" as a string?

I ask this because I don't know if it would be a bad practice, in this case, to launch the string directly, since if another developer were to use my method, they would have to know the exact order of each attribute.

```
public class getPhone(String color, String brand, String model{
 return (SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Color__c = color, Brand__c = brand, Model__c = model);}
```

Or

```
public class getPhone (Map<String,String> color, Map<String,String> brand, Map<String, String> model){ 
 String colorInput =(String)color.get('Color'); 
 String brandInput =(String)brand.get('Brand'); 
 String modelInput =(String)model.get('Model'); 

 return (SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Color__c = colorInput, Brand__c = brandInput, Model__c = modelInput);}
```

Comment: I think the answers here are good in they get into why a Map is a poor choice but I didn't see any mention of two guidelines I use all the time when it comes to software engineering. 1) YAGNI: if you don't have a need to query for a dozen different fields right now, then there's no need to over-engineer your method at this stage and 2) there's nothing wrong with a method signature that takes 3 (string) arguments. My rule of thumb is 5 parameters. After 5, then I start refactoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a map like that obfuscates the parameters, making it so developers have to read the method to know what parameters to use. Worse, these kinds of maps are case sensitive. I would strongly recommend you don't do this. If you have enough parameters that you'd want to do this, make a wrapper or Data Transfer Object.

Answer (score 2):

Just some general notes:

1. sfdcfox's answer is, as always, brilliant. Using a map like that isn't a great idea, and I'd go so far as to say it's a *bad* idea.
2. I like your desire to let other developers know what the parameters are, but I think the *right* way to solve this is with proper documentation. Apex-recipes (https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes) uses the npm package "@cparra/apexdocs" to generate standardized markdown files for classes. The per-method documentation block looks like this:

/**

- @description The doLoad method is required by the CacheBuilder interface
- This method needs to return an Object - and that's the key to the Cache
- builder interface - You must have this method return a single Object that
- is either calculated by this method, or returned from the Cache by the
- key
- @param key   String used to help generate the Cache Key
- @return     `Object` This object should be casted at the call location
- @group Platform Cache Recipes
- @see CanTheUser
- @example Account[] accounts = (Account[]) Cache.Session.get(PlatformCacheBuilderRecipes.class, 'myAccounts')
  */
  public Object doLoad(String key) {

So that's not rendering great, but those bullet points are *'s

Apexdocs understands certain tags, like @description and when run it generates docs like this markdown.

````
---
layout: default
---
# PlatformCacheBuilderRecipes class

demonstrates how to use the Cache.CacheBuilder Interface

---
## Methods
### `doLoad(String key)` → `Object`

The doLoad method is required by the CacheBuilder interface This method needs to return an Object - and that&apos;s the key to the Cache builder interface - You must have this method return a single Object that is either calculated by this method, or returned from the Cache by the key

#### Parameters
|Param|Description|
|-----|-----------|
|`key` |    String used to help generate the Cache Key |

#### Return

**Type**

Object

**Description**

`Object` This object should be casted at the call location

#### Example
```java
Account[] accounts = (Account[]) Cache.Session.get(PlatformCacheBuilderRecipes.class, 'myAccounts')
```

---
````

Generating and making this kind of documentation available makes it easy for your third party developers to consume your methods, and readily identify what order the parameters are in.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is quite incorrect. Assuming this is just a snippet I am ignoring those.

You can go for a `Map<String, String>` solution here, as you just need one parameter to pass:

Original Method:

```
public List<Product2> getPhone(String color, String brand, String model){
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Color__c = :color AND Brand__c = :brand AND Model__c = :model];
}
```

New Method :

```
public List<Product2> getPhone(Map<String, String> mapValuesByKey){
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Color__c = :mapValuesByKey.get('color') AND Brand__c = :mapValuesByKey.get('brand') AND Model__c = :mapValuesByKey.get('model')];
}
```

You can make key of the map as a global variable and use that when you `put` or `get` from Map.